# Can you know if an IP adres is malevolent?

Tags: security, ip

The question is in the question, another question was general info: [what info can you find out by knowing an IP, how and what tools/ sites are needed for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946122/what-info-can-you-find-out-by-knowing-an-ip-how-and-what-tools-sites-are-neede)

But I 'm wondering if you can also know if a user tries to do bad things by an IP adress?

Comment: Ok, is it normal if certain companies visit your website? I checked my IPs I saved of my unpublished website and found some names of particularly television companies. :S

Comment: @stark Funny, but probably best not to post that where people might not get the joke.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that a phone number´s owner is evil just because of the number if he calls you?
About activity of random IPs, this is the internet. Always some strange background "noise", even if nothing i wrong.

So no, you can´t determine the intentions of IP users, and it´s unlikely you are hacked just because IPs of some known company are accessing your site.